# Trouble Understanding broadcasting behavior for tensors

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, multiplication, tensor, array-broadcasting

I am trying to do element-wise multiplication of two tensors of dimensions (1,5,64) and (1,5). As far as I know, in spite of their dimension mismatch, broadcasting should allow this to work. So, I use this code:

```
x = tf.range(0,64*5)
x = tf.reshape(x, [1,5, 64])

y = tf.range(0,5)
y = tf.reshape(y, [1, 5])

prodct = x*y
```

This causes this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,5,64] vs. [1,5] [Op:Mul]
```

However If i reshape first tensor to dimension (1,64,5), then it works. Code:

```
x = tf.range(0,64*5)
x = tf.reshape(x, [1,64, 5])

y = tf.range(0,5)
y = tf.reshape(y, [1, 5])

prodct = x*y
```

I do not understand why the first code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [General Broadcasting Rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), when operating on two arrays, [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. **rightmost**) dimensions and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when

- **they are equal**, or
- **one of them is 1**

If these conditions are not met, a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together` exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting array is the size that is not 1 along each axis of the inputs.

[tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) also follows the same spirit. Check the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more examples and details. For your case, the rightmost dimension doesn't follow the rules and throws an error.

```
1, 5, 64
   1, 5
```

But this would work as it obeys the rules.

```
1, 64, 5
   1,  5
```

**Code**

In [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), and in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) for reference.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.arange(64*5).reshape(1, 64, 5)
b = np.arange(5).reshape(1,5)
(a*b).shape
(1, 64, 5)

import tensorflow as tf 
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(0,64*5), [1, 64, 5])
y = tf.reshape(tf.range(0,5), [1, 5])
(x*y).shape
TensorShape([1, 64, 5])
```